# Custom Search box in SharePoint Foundation 2010

Tags: search

I need to add custom search box in SharePoint Foundation 2010. I have to use my own customized search box with nearly 5 to 10 filter options. I heard that search box webpart can't be used in SharePoint Foundation 2010. So i need any alternative for that..

Comment: Your question is vague and not really stating exactly what you want. Please read the FAQ to understand how to construct questions.

Comment: Now i explained my ques. Please find solution soon..

Comment: how did you use your own customized search box? Is it just a search web part from server or something you created through visual studio?

Comment: Created in visual studio..

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the default searchbox by registering a delegate control on the SmallSearchInputBox.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
 <Control
  Id="SmallSearchInputBox"
  Sequence="10"
  ControlClass="Suren.CustomSearchBox" 
  ControlAssembly="Suren.Assemby, etcetc">
  <Property Name="SurensProp">someValue</Property>
 </Control> 
</Elements>
```